# python's requests do not handle cookies correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, python-requests, multipartform-data

I have problem with simple authorization and upload API script.

When authorized, client receives several cookies, including PHPSESSID cookie (in browser).

I use `requests.post` method with form data for authorization:

```
r = requests.post(url, headers = self.headers, data = formData)
self.cookies = requests.utils.dict_from_cookieja(r.cookies)
```

Headers are used for custom `User-Agent` only.

Authorization is 100% fine (there is a logout link on the page).
Later, i try to upload data using the authorized session cookies:

```
r = requests.post(url, files = files, data = formData, headers = self.headers, cookies = self.cookies)
```

But site rejects the request. If we compare the requests from script and google chrome (using Wireshark), there is no differences in request body.

Only difference is that **2** cookies sent by requests class, while google chrome sends **7**.

**Update**: Double checked, first request receives 7 cookies. post method just ignore half...

Comment: I'm not aware of any cookie issues with `requests`, no. Using a Chrome Incognito tab, how many cookies are set *on the first request to the site*? The site could very well alter behaviour based on the user agent or other request headers. Next, are you sure the page doesn't use a CSRF token embedded with the login form?

Comment: Next, what is the expiration date on the cookies? Are there specific flags set on those cookies? What happens when you use a `requests.Session()` object to manage the cookies?

Comment: @MartijnPieters my bad, i've solved the mistakes. I have no expirience with using `session` class, good advice for future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mistake in code was that i was **assigning** cookies from each next API request to the session cookies dictionary. On each request since logged in, cookies was 'reset' by upcoming response cookies, that's was the problem. As auth cookies are assigned only at login request, they were lost at the next request.

After each authorized request i use **update()**, not assigning.

```
self.cookies.update( requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(r.cookies) )
```

Solves my issue, upload works fine!

Comment: You should just be using a session so you don't have to handle them yourself